# Access is denied when I create a file in programfiles folder

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I created a wpf application. It will create a text file and store some data. In the time of implementation it's working fine(visual studio 2015). After I create a setup and install it in the same system I get the error:

> Access denied to create file C:\programFiles\test\hello.txt

This is my code :

```
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText("hello.txt"))
```

When debugging the file is created in the debug/bin folder.

Comment: You have to run your application with `Elevated Privileges` (`Run As Admin`)

Answer (score 4):

You can't just write to that folder without having the appropriate permissions. Your application should run elevated as administrator to be able to write to that folder.

I would advise you to use a folder that is writable without elevation, like the `%PROGRAMDATA%` folder.

Comment: No it does not. The folder the executable is compiled too is a non-elevated directory and free to write to. @palu

Comment: You're totally right, of course. I meant something like that but wasn't thinking straight. I still think it could be somewhat helpful to point out that the identity used to launch Visual Studio would have the ability to write to the program's current working directory since that's also where Visual Studio's compiler just wrote a binary.